# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to inflate  a layout into a fragment 
and i have #8: Error inflating class fragment
my View does not even creating it fall on the inflate 
how to inflate correctly the layout ?

my XML large:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <fragment 
                  android:id="@+id/first_page"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  class = "com.project.places.First_Page"   
                    />

        <fragment 
                  android:id="@+id/map"
                  android:layout_weight="2"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:name="com.project.places.Map_fragment"
                   />


    </LinearLayout>
```

my container :

```
    </FrameLayout>
```

my fragment layout:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10sp" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/search_By_Location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/location" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_By_Location_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Search By Your Current Location"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/search_By_City"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/city_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_By_City_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Search By City"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/favorits" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                android:src="@drawable/location_star"
                 />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/favorits_TextView"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                  android:text="Browser Favorites"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/history"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/location_clock" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/history_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Browser History"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
          </LinearLayout>

       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

java main :

```
    my class java first :


    package com.project.places;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class First_Page extends Fragment{


        onSearchTypeListener searchType_Callback;

        public interface onSearchTypeListener{
            public void searchTypeSelected(String type);
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_page, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            ImageButton by_city =(ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_By_City);
            by_city.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "by_city", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    searchType_Callback.searchTypeSelected("city");
                }
            });

            ImageButton by_location =(ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_By_Location);
            by_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "by_location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    searchType_Callback.searchTypeSelected("location");

                }
            });

            ImageButton favorits =(ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.favorits);
            favorits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "favorits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    searchType_Callback.searchTypeSelected("favorits");

                }
            });

            ImageButton history =(ImageButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.history);
            history.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "history", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    searchType_Callback.searchTypeSelected("history");

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

            try {
                searchType_Callback = (onSearchTypeListener)activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onSearchTypeListener");
            }
        }

    }
```

the LOG file

```
                01start activity ComponentInfoandroid.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
-   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
-   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
-   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
-   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
-   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
-   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
-   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
-   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
-   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
-   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
-   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
-   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
- Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
-   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
-   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
-   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
-   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
-   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
-   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:278)
-   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
-   at com.project.places.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
-   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
-   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
-   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
-   ... 11 more
- Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
-   at com.project.places.First_Page.onViewCreated(First_Page.java:36)
-   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:906)
-   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
-   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
-   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
-   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
-   ... 21 more
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: what do you mean, all the code ?

Comment: No, I mean the entire stack trace: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/115145

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    >
    

</FrameLayout>

Comment: That is not a stack trace. I even provided a link to a StackOverflow answer that explains what a stack trace is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/115145

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

Comment: `First_Page.java`, line 36, is causing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: That's what you mean?

Comment: check whether the package name for the class is correct and exists com.project.places.First_Page

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException - at com.project.places.First_Page.onViewCreated(First_Page.java:36
> ```

In your `onViewCreated()` you should access the fragment UI views with `view.findViewById()` instead of `getActivity().findViewById()`. The fragment isn't attached to the activity yet so it's not found in the activity's view hierarchy either.

Comment: i am getting 01-29 18:28:55.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 18:28:55.869: E/AndroidRuntime(22660): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.places/com.project.places.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: That's not the interesting part. What's intereseting is the "caused by" exception below. I've quoted the essential part from your question in this answer.

Comment: This :01-29 18:33:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22911): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f060013, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
01-29 18:33:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22911):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
01-29 18:33:43.930: E/AndroidRuntime(22911):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
android:name = "com.project.places.First_Page"
```

instead of

```
class = "com.project.places.First_Page"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/fragment_id"
    android:name="com.example.xxx.fragment.FragmentClassName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_layout" />
```

Try to add android:name for your xml fragment:).It works to me.

Answer (score 0):

I gets this error when tried to put the Activity to constructor like this:

```
public MyView (Activity activity) {
   super (activity);
}

public MyView (Activity activity, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super (activity, attrs);
}
```

Remember that you can only put a Context in custom views constructors like this:

```
public MyView (Context context) {
   super (context);
}

public MyView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super (context, attrs);
}
```